Understanding proof of orientability of the level set of a regular value in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$
Given $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ a $C^{\infty}$ function with 0 being a regular value, we know that $M = f^{-1}(0)$ is a manifold of dimension $n$. There is an answer given here, though I don't understanding something about it.
In particular, we define the form $\omega = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{i-1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_1 \wedge \cdots \widehat{dx_i} \cdots \wedge dx_{n+1}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and since
$$ df \wedge \omega = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \right)^2 \right) dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{n+1}$$
Now, we can conclude that $\eta = df \wedge \omega$ is non-vanishing for $p \in M$ (as it is a regular value, so the partials are never all 0 for points in $M$), BUT, this is only for $\eta$ as a top form on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so $\eta_p : (T_p \mathbb{R}^{n+1})^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ is non-vanishing, I agree, and in particular $\omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is non-vanishing on $M$ but how does this tell me that $\omega|_M$ as an $n$-form on the submanifold $M$ is non-vanishing?
It could very well be the case that a form that is non-vanishing on the parent manifold vanishes as a form restricted to the submanifold. Take $dx \in T^*\mathbb{R}^{2}$, this is non-vanishing as $dx(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}) = 1$ at every p, HOWEVER, $dx|_{S^1} \in T^*(S^1)$ vanishes at $p = (1,0)$ since the tangent vectors there are all of the form $k \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $(dx|_{S^1})_p(k \frac{\partial}{\partial y}) = 0$. So what about the proof above helps us conclude that $\omega|_M$ is an orientation form on $M$, and not just a form on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that is non-vanishing at points in $M$.

"Regular set" is not the standard language. You mean the preimage of a regular value, of course. There are signs missing in the definition of $\omega$. The point is that if the restriction of $\omega$ to $M$ vanishes at some point $p$, then $df\wedge\omega$ will vanish on $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ because $df(p)$ vanishes on the tangent space to $M$. Take a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ for $T_pM$ and $v_{n+1}$ normal to $M$. Only the term $df(p)(v_{n+1})\omega(p)(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ will occur when you evaluate $(df\wedge\omega)(p)(v_1,\dots,v_n,v_{n+1})$.

I've edited the question with the right notation, but I understand now. Thanks!

It was a good question. Why don't you write up an answer?
